# What does buying a drink do?

Tags: poker-night-2

I've bought a drink for Ash and Sam and it's suppose to make them show their tells more often the more they drink. Does the longer they play (and drink) in that game make their tells more noticeable?

I've noticed that after the game I've bought a drink in, I can't buy a drink for that character again. Does buying a drink for them permanently make their tells more noticeable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, giving the other players a drink basically increases the 'tell sensitivity'
so now, if they have a moderately good hand, they will have a 'Positive' tell, and if they have a slightly bad hand, they will give a 'Negative' tell.

However, in Omaha the AI can often be one card short of a Flush with several community cards to go, and have very negative tells - But they could be bluffing however. like in the first Poker Night, all the characters have different personalities (i.e Sam is like Tycho; folds a lot, but the Heavy never folds unless he has a really rubbish hand, etc)